# mix randomly intarray(use shuffle void in android)

Tags: android

I try to mix randomly array. I use `shuffle(Arrays.asList(array))` void but when taking a result, numbers are not mixed and toast class every time return number 5. Where is my problem?  I think I must put new numbers in a new array.

```
int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
String aString = Integer.toString(array[4]);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), aString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: 6 words to transform your development.  Learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: could you explain more.

Comment: @Simon:thank you this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

i found:

```
Integer array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
String aString = Integer.toString(array[4]);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), aString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

thanks to @Simon